# Nouns denoting a state and the point of its initiation

Tags: meaning, nouns, vocabulary

The word incarnation, according to [Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incarnation), has two meanings:

1) the act of incarnating
2) the state of being incarnate

So, this word can denote a state, as well as the moment of initiation of that state.

Are there any other such words in English? is there any official term for such words?

Answer (score 1):

approximate
articulate
aspirate
associate
confederate
desolate
elongate
ejaculate
estimate
filtrate
graduate
infiltrate
initiate
isolate
moderate
probate, and
 
erect

Comment: Thanks, but I need something more like resurrection, completion, consummation, shock, etc.

Comment: I think this answer is half baked.